# sql get last date for each month for every category

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table that looks like this

```
item.    date.     
a        28/2/22
a        29/2/22
a        16/3/22 
b        31/1/22 
b        26/1/22
b        29/3/22
```

I want the last date for each month like so..

```
item   monthYear   monthYear_lastDate
a      Jan-2022      -
a      Feb-2022     29/2/22
a      Mar-2022     16/3/22
b      Jan-2022     31/1/22 
b      Feb-2022      - 
b      Mar-2022     29/3/22
```

How can I write a query to get this information? Is it possible without scaffolding / using a secondary table containing each month's start and end dates?

NULL values for some months in output are because data for that month is unavailable in input.

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working for you?

Comment: What happened to the two rows that have NULL in the "*monthYear_lastDate*" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
select t.item, FORMAT(t.date,"MM-YYYY") AS monthYear FROM t, MAX(date) AS monthYear_lastDate
from tablename t
inner join (
    select username, max(date) as monthYear_lastDate
    from t
    group by item
) tm on t.item = tm.item and t.date = tm.monthYear_lastDate
```